# Bootstrap 4 - Auto expand node on page load

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap 4, js, etc.

I want to be able to expand a node automatically when the page loads for the first time. I tried altering the data-collapse but it goes back to collapsed mode. I also tried js, but it expands and automatically collapses again.

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553968/bootstrap-treeview-how-auto-expand-parent-nodes), but it does not apply to bootstrap 4 as there is no tree component.

This the code that is not working. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li id="expandthis">
        <a href="#ulExpCol_10" data-toggle="collapse"              
                       onclick="$('#thisCollapsedChevron_10').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90')">
             <i class="zz_TreeParent" id="thisCollapsedChevron_10"></i>
               Level 1 Parent Link 1--
               </a>
                <!-- Children -->
                <ul id="ulExpCol_10" class="ml-3 list-unstyled collapse"
                    <li>
                       <a href="#item-001-001" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                          Submenu Item-11
                       </a>
                    </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#item-001-002" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                        Submenu Item-12
                     </a>
                 </li>

               </ul>
            </li>            
     <li>
         <a href="#item-001-002" class="zz_TreeParent">
           Level 1 Item-2-No Children
        </a>
     </li>
```

**The JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#expandthis').collapse('toggle');     
  });
```

**JSFiddle:**
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/c97g3ymu/14/)

Comment: So you want `Level 1 Parent Link 1` to be automatically open when entering the page?

Comment: @AdrianPop yes please.

Comment: Can you replace the `$('#expandthis').collapse('toggle');` line with `   `$('#ulExpCol_10').collapse('toggle');` and try again, please? Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adrianpop/5b9n2jx6/). The first menu seems to be very opened when you are entering the page. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: @AdrianPop, you are correct. Please make this an answer and I will mark it as such. One last question, why is the css rule ".zz_TreeParent" not making the first node Black? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace the `$('#expandthis').collapse('toggle');` line with `$('#ulExpCol_10').collapse('toggle');` and it will work accordingly.

When applying `$('#expandthis').collapse('toggle');` to `<li id="expandthis">` nothing happens, since the list element does not have a data-toggle attached. You want to toggle the actual sub-menu, as in the working fiddle below.

For the part where the color of the parent should be black: the text is actually inside the `a` element, not inside the `i` element, so you have to apply the class there. If you don't want the underline effect when hovering the menu, you could also add `text-decoration: none !important;` (the `!important` is needed because you are using Bootstrap).

```
.zz_TreeParent {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.zz_TreeParent: hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ulExpCol_10').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```css
.zz_TreeParent {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.zz_TreeParent: hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.zz_TreeLeaf {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li id="expandthis">
        <a href="#ulExpCol_10" data-toggle="collapse"              
         onclick="$('#thisCollapsedChevron_10').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90')" class="zz_TreeParent">
             <i class="zz_TreeParent" id="thisCollapsedChevron_10"></i>
               Level 1 Parent Link 1--
               </a>
                <!-- Children -->
                <ul id="ulExpCol_10" class="ml-3 list-unstyled collapse"
                    <li>
                       <a href="#item-001-001" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                          Submenu Item-11
                       </a>
                    </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#item-001-002" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                        Submenu Item-12
                     </a>
                 </li>
         
               </ul>
            </li>
   
   
     <li>
        <a href="#item-001-002" class="zz_TreeParent">
           Level 1 Item-2-No Children
        </a>
     </li>
   
   </ul>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for explaining the original question and the extra coloring issue. I sometimes get confused after trying so many things. Excellent answer.